# Change view to what the camera is viewing

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have created a world with a robot, a pioneer 2DX and added a camera.

I want to see what the camera is seeing but I don't know how.

How can I change to what the camera is seeing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19041/change-view-to-what-the-camera-is-viewing/) by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. On the top menu, choose `Window -> Topic Visualization`
2. Look for `gazebo.msgs.ImageStamped` and your camera's topic under it
3. Double click it

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2